# SWF works locally but not loaded from server

Tags: mod-rewrite, unity-game-engine, flash, swfobject

Here is the deal. I have SWF build with Unity and embedded into HTML page with swfobject. It works perfectly well when I load page locally ([zip](http://dybydx.org/unity_samples/Ballistics/Ballistics.zip)), but it always says "Movie not loaded" when I try to load page. [from server](http://dybydx.org/unity_samples/Ballistics/Ballistics.html)

I have already inspect similar embedded movies ([this one](http://durej.com/unity/cardemo/), and [this one](http://www.stimunation.com/previews/labs/unityToFlashExport/unityFlashShadowDemo/)) and found no differences in HTML code neither in scripts. So I suspect the source of problem is my server, most likely its rewrite rules. Yesterday I tried to understand the meaning of this file using multiple manuals, forum threads et cetera:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php52 .php .php5 .php4 .php3

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Once upon a time, before Google Translate even exists, I have spent a whole day to succesfully translate an article from simplified Chinese to Russian (with zero experience in Chinese and overall C- for school course of Russian). So it was surprisingly frustrating to me when I have spent same period of time to a few strings of declarative code and still have no idea even if am I right and it will solve my problem.

So I will gratefully appreciate a helpful answer or two.

Comment: Hey, I cannot extract the .zip file here, can you double check if its ok? The "from server" link just displays a blank page, is that your problem?

Comment: Hi, d4Rk, I have reuploaded .zip file, and yes, the link displays just a blank movie. It tells "movie was not loaded" if you will click RMB on it.

Comment: Works locally, also with your provided `.htaccess`. Did you try to remove this `.htaccess` temporary to check if that's really causing your problems? Could you provide more information on your server's setup?

Comment: Yep, I had tried it without .htaccess with no success. To my shame I have no idea what kind of server setup may affect my problem. Apache handlers? MIME types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some further tests, sadly there are no errors on the console. But it pretty much looks like there's something wrong with your `.swf` file on the server, because when I download the file from your server it is not working locally either. (Did you try that before?)

How did you upload the file? There are many sources on the web (e.g. http://www.techtutorials.net/articles/ftp_binary_or_ascii__a.html) that point out that you must use `binary` mode for files like `.swf`.

**=> Upload the file again using `binary` mode**

Some other thoughts:

- Check the file permission of the `.swf` file, should have at least read rights (e.g. `644`)
- Check for the mime type in Apache: `AddType application/x-shockwave-flash swf` 
  Source: http://www.htaccess-guide.com/adding-mime-types/

Let me know if all of this doesn't solve your problem.